# maestro launches expo app and shows "development build" instead of app

Tags: react-native, expo, maestro

I am using `expo` `SDK 49` and `maestro` for E2E user testing.
When I run `maestro` now, a page appears that say "Development Build" and does not show my app anymore.

Can someone please explain what is this page, why this is showing and how I can get `maestro` to load my app again?

I have tried running
`npx react-native build-android` and `eas build --profile development --platform android`

When I run `npx expo run:android` the app shows correctly

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to not have expo development build page show when app starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742108/how-to-not-have-expo-development-build-page-show-when-app-starts)

Answer (score 2):

Similar question with answer: [how to not have expo development build page show when app starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742108/how-to-not-have-expo-development-build-page-show-when-app-starts/76751360#76751360)

Development build shows when you build with `"developmentClient": true` in `eas.json`

From the documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/introduction/

> Development builds of your app are Debug builds of your project. It includes the expo-dev-client library, which allows you to develop and debug projects using Expo CLI. Building your project with Expo allows you to make most changes in JavaScript.

You can create a build in the `eas.json` that has `"developmentClient": false`

Answer (score 2):

You may manually close the **Development Build** UI and switch to your app using these Maestro commands:

```
- runFlow:
    when:
      visible:
        text: "http.*"
    commands:
      - tapOn: "http.*"
- runFlow:
    when:
      visible: "Continue"
    commands:
      - tapOn: "Continue"
- runFlow:
    when:
      visible: "Toggle performance monitor"
    commands:
      - tapOn:
          point: 50%,10%
```