# how to not have expo development build page show when app starts?

Tags: react-native, expo, maestro

Currently using `expo` and `react native`. I'm using `maestro` for E2E testing and everytime the app launches I see the Development Build page comes up first. This is pretty annoying for E2E testing. How can I get rid of that page so that `maestro` tests will see the first page of the app every time on launch?

[image]

Comment: You can also add the `disableOnboarding` suffix to the URL to remove the welcome modal. More details here: https://docs.moropo.com/guides/react-native-expo#disabling-onboarding

Answer (score 2):

I had to create a build with `developmentClient: false` and then `prebuild` and then build locally and then install the builds in my simulators.

Note: You do not have to build locally but I was reaching my maximum EAS builds so I'm starting to do them locally.

These docs helped me...

https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

https://docs.expo.dev/build/eas-json/

https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/

https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/simulators/

My updated `eas.json`

```
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.16.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "simulator": {
      "developmentClient": false,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Steps and commands I used to fix this were

IOS
Open simulator
Xcode => Open Developer Tool => Simulator

Android
Open Virtual Device manager and create simulator

`npx expo prebuild --clean`
Removed android and ios files and creates the files again

`eas build -p android --profile simulator --local`
Locally build android simulator and device apk (no dev tools)

`adb devices`
See what devices are online

`adb install build-1690167210800.apk`
Install app from previous build

`eas build -p ios --profile simulator --local`
Locally build IOS simulator build file (no dev tools)
Returns something like…
You can find the build artifacts in path/to/build/build-1690168440203.tar.gz

1. Extract the build artifacts: `tar -xvzf build-1690168440203.tar.gz`
2. Install the app on the simulator: `xcrun simctl install booted abut.app`

Test E2E using maestro
`maestro test maestro`